# Python // PySide6 // Ругается антивирус

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside6, pyside, python-3.11

Делаю калькулятор для школьного проекта, но после компиляции `pyinstaller -F -w main.py` в exe некоторые антивирусы ругаются, в т. ч. Windows SmartScreen Defender: узнал, когда скинул другу, да и некоторые антивирусники в VirusTotal ругаются. Как решать?
Скомпилированный вариант: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/LciT8yHboCM6Gw

Код:
`main.py`

```
import sys
import math
import re
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy, QWidget)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Функционал
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.result_status = False
        
        self.ui.pushButton_percent.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('%', 'special'))
        self.ui.pushButton_cleanEntrance.clicked.connect(lambda: self.cleanEntrance())
        self.ui.pushButton_clear.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clear())
        self.ui.pushButton_delete.clicked.connect(lambda: self.delete())
        self.ui.pushButton_fraction.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('1/', 'special'))
        self.ui.pushButton_square.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('^', 'op'))
        self.ui.pushButton_squareRoot.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('√', 'special'))
        self.ui.pushButton_divide.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('/', 'op'))
        self.ui.pushButton_seven.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('7'))
        self.ui.pushButton_eight.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('8'))
        self.ui.pushButton_nine.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('9'))
        self.ui.pushButton_multiply.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('*', 'op'))
        self.ui.pushButton_four.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('4'))
        self.ui.pushButton_five.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('5'))
        self.ui.pushButton_six.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('6'))
        self.ui.pushButton_minus.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('-', 'op'))
        self.ui.pushButton_one.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('1'))
        self.ui.pushButton_two.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('2'))
        self.ui.pushButton_three.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('3'))
        self.ui.pushButton_plus.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('+', 'op'))
        self.ui.pushButton_negate.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('-', 'special'))
        self.ui.pushButton_zero.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('0'))
        self.ui.pushButton_point.clicked.connect(lambda: self.entrance('.'))
        self.ui.pushButton_equal.clicked.connect(lambda: self.calculate())

    def clear(self):
        # Очистка
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('0')
        self.format()

    def cleanEntrance(self):
        # Чистый вход
        self.clear()

    def delete(self):
        # Удаление
        if not self.result_status == True:
            text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
            text = text[:len(text)-1]
            if len(text) == 0:
                text = '0'
            self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)
            self.format_font()
        else:
            self.clear()

    def entrance(self, symbol, type = None):
        # Ввод
        if self.result_status == True and not (type == 'op' or 'special'):
            self.clear()
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        if type == 'special':
            numbers = re.split(r'[-/^*+]', text)
            if symbol in '1/√':
                if not numbers[-1] == '':
                    result = symbol + '(' + numbers[-1] + ')'
                else:
                    result = symbol + '(' + numbers[-2] + ')'
            elif symbol == '-' and text != '0':
                result = symbol + numbers[-1]
            else:
                try:
                    result = str(float(numbers[-2])/100*float(numbers[-1]))
                except:
                    text = '0'
            text = text[:len(text)-len(numbers[-1])] + result
        elif type == 'op':
            if text[-1] in '-/^*+':
                text = text[:len(text)-1]
            text = text + symbol
        else:
            if text == '0' and symbol != '.':
                text = ''
            text = text + symbol
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)
        self.format()
        self.result_status = False

    def format(self):
        # Форматирование
        self.format_font()
        self.format_needless()
#       self.format_length()

    def format_font(self):
        # Форматирование шрифта
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        if len(text) > 11:
            self.ui.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 24pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
            if len(text) > 14:
                self.ui.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 20pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
                if len(text) > 17:
                    self.ui.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 18pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
        else:
            self.ui.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 30pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)

    def format_needless(self):
        # Удаление '.0' в конце числа
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        try:
            if text[-2] + text[-1] == '.0':
                numbers = re.split(r'[-/^*+]', text)
                text = text.replace(numbers[-1], str(math.trunc(float(numbers[-1]))))
        except:
            pass
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)

    def format_length(self, text):
        # Work In Progress!!!
        pass

    def calculate(self):
        # Счёт
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        if text[-1] in '-/^*+':
            numbers = re.split(r'[-/^*+]', text)
            result = numbers[-2]
            text = text + result
        text = text.replace('√', 'math.sqrt')
        text = text.replace('^', '**')
        try:
            result = str(eval(text))
            text = result
        except:
            text = 'Ошибка'
        self.result_status = True
        self.format_length(text)
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(text)
        self.format()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`ui_main.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'ui_main.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 6.5.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy, QWidget)
# import assets_rc

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")

        font = QFont()
        font.setFamilies([u"Noto Sans SC"])
        font.setPointSize(11)

#       icon = QIcon()
#       icon.addFile(u":/assets/assets/icon.png", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)

        MainWindow.resize(330, 470)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(330, 470))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QSize(330, 470))
#       MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"font: 11pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")

        self.layoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName(u"layoutWidget")
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(10, 170, 311, 291))

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)

        self.pushButton_percent = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_percent.setObjectName(u"pushButton_percent")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_percent.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_percent.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_cleanEntrance = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_cleanEntrance.setObjectName(u"pushButton_cleanEntrance")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_cleanEntrance.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_cleanEntrance.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_clear = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_clear.setObjectName(u"pushButton_clear")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_clear.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_clear.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_delete = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_delete.setObjectName(u"pushButton_delete")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_delete.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_delete.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_fraction = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_fraction.setObjectName(u"pushButton_fraction")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_fraction.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_fraction.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_square = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_square.setObjectName(u"pushButton_square")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_square.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_square.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_squareRoot = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_squareRoot.setObjectName(u"pushButton_squareRoot")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_squareRoot.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_squareRoot.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_divide = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_divide.setObjectName(u"pushButton_divide")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_divide.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_divide.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_multiply = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_multiply.setObjectName(u"pushButton_multiply")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_multiply.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_multiply.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_minus = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_minus.setObjectName(u"pushButton_minus")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_minus.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_minus.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_plus = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_plus.setObjectName(u"pushButton_plus")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_plus.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_plus.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_equal = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_equal.setObjectName(u"pushButton_equal")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_equal.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_equal.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_point = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_point.setObjectName(u"pushButton_point")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_point.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_point.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_negate = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_negate.setObjectName(u"pushButton_negate")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_negate.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_negate.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_zero = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_zero.setObjectName(u"pushButton_zero")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_zero.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_zero.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_one = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_one.setObjectName(u"pushButton_one")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_one.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_one.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_two = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_two.setObjectName(u"pushButton_two")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_two.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_two.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_three = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_three.setObjectName(u"pushButton_three")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_three.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_three.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_four = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_four.setObjectName(u"pushButton_four")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_four.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_four.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_five = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_five.setObjectName(u"pushButton_five")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_five.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_five.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_six = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_six.setObjectName(u"pushButton_six")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_six.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_six.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_seven = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_seven.setObjectName(u"pushButton_seven")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_seven.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_seven.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.pushButton_eight = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_eight.setObjectName(u"pushButton_eight")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_eight.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_eight.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        
        self.pushButton_nine = QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_nine.setObjectName(u"pushButton_nine")
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_nine.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_nine.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(10, 70, 311, 91))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet(u"font: 700 30pt \"Noto Sans SC\";")
        self.lineEdit.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTrailing|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(21)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_percent, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_cleanEntrance, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_clear, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_delete, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_fraction, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_square, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_squareRoot, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_divide, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_seven, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_eight, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_nine, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_multiply, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_four, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_five, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_six, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_minus, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_one, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_two, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_three, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_plus, 4, 3, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_negate, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_zero, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_point, 5, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_equal, 5, 3, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041a\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043a\u0443\u043b\u044f\u0442\u043e\u0440", None))
        self.pushButton_point.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u".", None))
        self.pushButton_negate.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u00b1"))
        self.pushButton_equal.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"=", None))
        self.pushButton_divide.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u00f7", None))
        self.pushButton_three.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None))
        self.pushButton_multiply.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u00d7", None))
        self.pushButton_six.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"6", None))
        self.pushButton_plus.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"+", None))
        self.pushButton_seven.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"7", None))
        self.pushButton_fraction.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1/x", None))
        self.pushButton_nine.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"9", None))
        self.pushButton_clear.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"C", None))
        self.pushButton_squareRoot.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u00b2\u221ax", None))
        self.pushButton_four.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"4", None))
        self.pushButton_zero.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"0", None))
        self.pushButton_one.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None))
        self.pushButton_delete.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u232b", None))
        self.pushButton_eight.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"8", None))
        self.pushButton_five.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"5", None))
        self.pushButton_percent.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"%", None))
        self.pushButton_square.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"X\u207F", None))
        self.pushButton_minus.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u2212", None))
        self.pushButton_two.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None))
        self.pushButton_cleanEntrance.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"CE", None))
        self.lineEdit.setText('0')
    # retranslateUi
```

Comment: Если же скомпилировать без флага -F, то SmartScreen не ругается, но и файлов куча

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказал [@WtfIsGoingOn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/366732/wtfisgoingon) Антивирусы не любят самораспаковывающиеся архивы.

Несколько возможных решений:

### 1) Использовать другой инструмент компиляции.

Насколько мне известно, [Nuitka](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka) Не имеет такой проблемы, попробуйте использовать ее вместо pyinstaller'a

### 2) Попробуйте отключить `-F` Опцию

Во многих случаях это помогает, хоть и гораздо менее удобно использовать такой вариант программы.

### 3) Попробуйте использовать b64 трюк:

Скажу честно, сам я не уверен, что этот способ действительно работает, но встречал его упоминания несколько раз:

Оберните ваш код в b64 и запустите через exec. Примерно так:

```py
import base64

your_code = base64.b64encode(b"""

# Ваш код.  

import sys
import math
import re
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy, QWidget)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Функционал
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.result_status = False
        
# Продолжение вашего кода...
""")

exec(base64.b64decode(your_code))
```

Comment: Nuitka, кстати, как раз переводит код в C, а потом компилирует его, а третий способ не избавляет от архива, поэтому думаю, что не сработает.

Comment: Я воспользовался Nutika, теперь детектов еще больше: 16, если компилировать в 1 файл и 4 детекта в противном случае.

Comment: В случае если я закидываю на VT версию, скомпилированную Pyinstaller без флага -F (--onefile), тогда детектов 6, SmartScreen не ругается вроде.

Answer (score 2):

При "компиляции" `.py` в `.exe`, то файл `.exe` является самораспаковывающимся архивом. При запуске программы все файлы проекта распаковываются во временную область, на это и ругаются антивирусы.

Что бы этого избежать вам нужно преобразовать ваш `Python` код в `C` с помощью `cython`, а потом уже скомпилировать код на `C` в файл `.exe`